# Log4j1.x migration to log4j-1.2-api. Need to use AbstractAppender instead of AppenderSkeleton

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j

Problem:

- Unable to use log4j.properties to attach a custom appender that extends AbstractAppender.

Background:

- I recently updated my project to Log4j2 using the bridge Log4j-1.2-api as a requirement.
- Updated all imports and logger methods. No problems so far.
- Updated a custom appender class that extended AppenderSkeleton to now use AbstractAppender. The following error was generated:

```
19:11:25,791 ERROR [MSC service thread 1-1:stderr]:71 - log4j:ERROR The class "org.apache.log4j.Appender" was loaded by 
19:11:25,792 ERROR [MSC service thread 1-1:stderr]:71 - log4j:ERROR [ModuleClassLoader for Module "org.jboss.log4j.logmanager" version 1.1.6.Final-redhat-00001 from local module loader @79b4d0f (finder: local module finder @6b2fad11 (roots: C:\Programs\jboss-eap-7.2\modules,C:\Programs\jboss-eap-7.2\modules\system\layers\base))] whereas object of type 
19:11:25,792 ERROR [MSC service thread 1-1:stderr]:71 - log4j:ERROR "com.mydomain.log4j.CustomAppender" was loaded by [ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.MyApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader].
19:11:25,792 ERROR [MSC service thread 1-1:stderr]:71 - log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "errorLogAppender".
```

log4j.properties

```
appender.errorLogAppender=com.mydomain.log4j.CustomAppender
```

Questions:

How do I use Log4j-1.2-api while maintaining the same log4j.properties file and fixing the part that lets me use the new CustomAppender that extends AbstractAppender?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix and match. If you want to use a Log4j 2 Appender you must use a Log4j 2 configuration file. If you want to try your log4j 1.x Appender and see if it works with your log4j 1.x configuration file follow the instructions at [Log4j 1.x Compatibility](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/compatibility.html). That said, then you really should use a Log4j 2.x configuration.

One item to notice though, is that the error messages you are getting are coming from Log4j 1.x, not Log4j 2.  This means you have not fully removed Log4j 1 from your system. The second line would indicate it is integrated into JBoss.

Finally, you may not even need your custom Appender. I have found that when upgrading many users don't really look at the problem they are really trying to solve and instead just try to migrate the source without considering why it is needed. It is quite possible that Log4j 2 might already contain a component that will solve whatever the issue was.